# Using HTML Form Input Type File?

Tags: html, forms, http

I have a HTML form as follows:

```
<form action="/AddFile" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="filedata"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add File"/>
</form>
```

When I use it and submit a file called `foo` with content `bar` the POST request contains `filedata=foo` not `filedata=bar` as expected.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get the content of the file?

Answer (score 1):

One you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form.

Two you need to get the files from $_FILES instead.

Three I think it's `file_get_contents($_FILES['filedata']['tmp_name']);` to get the file's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup lacks the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, which is needed when a file field is present. See HTML 4.01 spec on [`form` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3).

Using `multipart/form-data`, the file contents get sent. The rest depends on your server-side handler.